# Беременный живот

Tags: грамотная-речь, словосочетания

**Беременный живот** — как вы оцените нормативность такой конструкции?
Имеется в виду ***живот беременной*** или ***напоминающий живот беременной***.

Контекст — на ваше усмотрение. Хоть такой:
*Певица Популярная показала свой беременный живот*.

Answer (score 2):

Судя по книжкам, корректоры в массовом порядке это пропускают, стало быть, полагают нормативным. Нет более конкретного прилагательного с таким корнем, "обременённый" имеет другие смыслы. Контекст, на мой взгляд, *имеет значение*,  в том смысле, что отвлеченно, как самостоятельная сущность (напр. "похожесть на БЖ") эта конструкция воспринимается странно (БЖ не должен "жить своей жизнью"), в то время как "свой/её БЖ" (где не подходит замена на "живот беременной") выглядит вполне терпимо (БЖ как бы существует "под контролем").